How to check if NodeTreeInterfaceItem is Open Or Closed with Python?
Since Blender 4.0 there are these new panels NodeTreeInterfaceItem that can be added in the Group node, you can declare if default_closed or not.
Here the problem:
How do I get if in the node the panel is open or closed like here in the example?
I have not found any API documentation about it and I am not even sure if it can be done.

It would be interesting to understand if there is some way to know if the "Output" or "Input" panel is open or closed.

Well.. every input (and every output) contains the bool value named .show_expanded
As far as I know, (in context of NodeGroup values) expanded/collapsed could be only two things: the group node itself and panels.
Since node itself is being set to be collapsed/expanded by the bool named .hide  — this .show_expanded boolean definitely is related to the input/output panels.
BUT panels are never included either to inputs or outputs property collections, so this .show_expanded just cannot be applied to them (but looks like this value designed to be used for this exact purpose)
I see two possible explanations of such paradox:

This is some kind of bug

This functionality is under development - so cannot be used yet


Hence I suggest you to report this inconsistency as a bug – and wait for an official answer, which will explain:

is it either a bug
an unfinished feature
or another thing.


P.S.
If you receive an official answer, please post it here (either as an answer or as a comment)

